# Как правильно в модели связать поле с родной таблицей Django?

Tags: python, django

Добрый день!

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно в модели связать поле с родной таблицей Django auth_user (чтобы при добавлении в базу записывался id пользователя).

И стоит ли использовать родную авторизацию и регистрацию Django если она подходит под проект или лучше делать что-то свое?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Связать объекты с юзером элементарно - `user = models.ForeignKey('auth.user')`, в свежих версиях Django несложно сделать свою модель пользователя, но если вас устраивает стандартный - берите для начала его.

Comment: user = models.ForeignKey('auth.user') user_id = models.ManyToManyField(user, related_name='+') делаю вот так, но сервер говорит, что ManyToManyField требует имя модели или self. Я уже и user в '' писал и просто 'auth.user', но он все ругается.

Comment: 'auth.User', простите, ошибся. Класс модели с заглавной пишется.

Comment: Спасибо, Заработало! Буду знать.